# Is there any way to import constants from a .js file into a .graphql file without using graphql-compose?

Tags: import, enums, graphql

I am looking to create an ENUM in my graphql defintions/types to be used by other types. I am already using the constants required in core .js files and I would like to import them directly into the .graphql files in which my definitions reside.

The .graphql files are imported as follows: -

```
import { importSchema } from "graphql-import"
export const typeDefs = importSchema("graphql/schema.graphql")
export default typeDefs


import resolvers from "@graphql/resolvers"
import typeDefs from "@graphql/schema"

const schema = makeExecutableSchema({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
})
```

I am aware I can do this using graphql-compose putting my typeDefs in .js files but I would like to avoid that extra step and do it directly if possible. Thanks.

Comment: That hinges on how you are importing them (fs, webpack, babel) and how you're consuming them (apollo, yoga, makeExecutableSchema, etc)

Comment: makeExecutableSchema. Currently my server app is being run through an NPM script (currently in dev).

Comment: And how are you importing them? Or better yet, maybe you could update your question with the relevant code.

Comment: Original post updated.